# Are [Wieferich] primes the only solutions to the equation $2^{k-1} \equiv 1 \pmod{k^2}$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, elementary-proofs

While studying a certain Diophantine equation in the squarefree integer $k \ge 2$, I believe I have proven the necessary restriction

$$2^{k-1} \equiv 1\!\!\pmod{k^2}.  \qquad(\star)$$

Based on what I read about Wieferich primes on Wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wieferich_prime), if $k$ is a prime, it must be a Wieferich prime. So far, so good.

However, I haven’t found anything — on Wikipedia or elsewhere — that proves there are **no composite solutions** to the congruence ($\star$). Is that statement true? If so, what’s an easy proof? If not, what's an easy disproof?

Many thanks,
Kieren.

*n.b.* I asked this same question on MSE earlier today (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/497810/are-wieferich-primes-the-only-solutions-to-2n-1-equiv-1-pmodn2), but now realize it might be more suitable here due to its possible complexity. Apologies if that's inappropriate.

Comment: Your condition certainly requires $2^{k-1} \equiv 1\!\!\pmod{k}$ which makes $k$ a prime or a $2$-pseuedoprime. You can find the first few and a link to a longer list at http://oeis.org/A001567. At least none of those listed has the property.

Comment: Wouldn't an easy proof of that give an easy proof of PRIMES in P?

Comment: @WillSawin Why? Suppose I compute $2^{k-1} \equiv 1 \mod k$ and $2^{k-1} \not \equiv 1 \mod k^2$. How do I know whether $k$ is prime?

Comment: According to http://oeis.org/A001567 "There are only two known numbers n such that n^2 divides 2^(n-1) - 1, A001220(n) = {1093, 3511}".

Comment: Not quite what you want, but there are composite $k$ such that $2^{\phi(k)}\equiv1\pmod{k^2}$, where $\phi$ is the Euler totient function. $3279=3\times1093$ is such a number. A reference is Agoh, Dilcher, and Skula, Fermat quotients for composite moduli, J Number Theory 66 (1997) 29-50, MR1467188 (98h:11002).

Comment: Shouldn't the sum of the inverses of the (square-free) $2$-pseudoprimes diverge to $+\infty$? If this is true (and I believe it is not known, but considered plausible), then on naive probabilistic (heuristic) grounds there are surely infinitely many such composite $k$: just note that the residue classes of $(2^{k-1} - 1)/k \mod{k}$ are expected to be distributed uniformly. (Also there should be finitely many positive integers $k$ for which the congruence holds mod $k^3$, but this is one of those questions about basic arithmetic whose answer we will probably never know.)

Comment: Indeed, you can find in this paper by Pomerance a precise conjectural distribution of the pseudoprimes; in particular, there should be more $2$-pseudoprimes than there are primes, and the heuristic applies to answer your question negatively: http://www.dei.unipd.it/~geppo/AA/DOCS/pseudoprimes.pdf .

Comment: As a matter of fact, even the sum of the inverses of (say, square-free, as you insist in the question) Carmichael numbers - those which are pseudoprime to any base prime to $k$ - would be expected to diverge. Just as well, there should be a subset $S$ of pair-wise coprime $k$'s with $\sum_S 1/k = +\infty$. For those, mod $k$ residues are to be considered as "independent events," as typical in heuristics about primes. Then note that, as $k$ runs through $S$, $(2^{k-1}-1)/k$ would be expected to take the residue $0$ with probability $1/k$.

Comment: @DavidSpeyer: Thanks for the link. Now I just need to prove that no composites >3511 satisfy the congruence — for my purpose, I don’t need to find any primes >3511 which do, or prove that no more do.

Comment: All I was trying to say was that the same heuristic which predicts that there should be about $\log\log{X}$ primes $p \leq X$ with $p^2 \mid 2^p - 2$, but only $O(1)$ (i.e., finitely many) with $p^3 \mid 2^p - 2$, suggests that your statement is false for infinitely many $k$, although it certainly has no known counterexamples.

Comment: @Vesselin, I believe Carmichael numbers are guaranteed to be squarefree.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson: You are right, I was careless here. If $k$ is Carmichael and $p$ a prime factor, then the condition $k \mid (p+1)^k-p-1$ certainly precludes $p^2 \mid k$.

Comment: Since these are precisely the base 2 pseudoprimes whose prime divisors are all Wieferich, there is no easy disproof: none of the very few known candidates work.

Comment: @François: Why would the prime factors be Wieferich? In any case, as noted above, it appears that the Wieferich primes 1093 and 3511 (the only two known) are the only known integers $k > 1$ for which $k^2 \mid 2^{k-1}-1$. This does not say anything at all, however; for instance, there are expected to be more Carmichael numbers than there are primes, contrary to what the list at http://oeis.org/A002997 would appear to suggest (e.g., the smallest one being 561).

Comment: @Vesselin: The order of $2$ mod $p^2$ is either the order of $2$ mod $p$ (when $p$ is Wieferich) or $p$ times that. If $p \mid k$ and the order of $2$ mod $k^2$ divides $k-1$ then the second case is impossible.

Comment: Please ask only one question per post. Therefore -1.

Answer (score 8):

This was a comment but it's actually a partial answer...

First, note that for an odd prime $p$ the order of $2$ mod $p^2$ is either equal to the order of $2$ mod $p$ or exactly $p$ times that. The first case happens if and only if $p$ is a Wieferich prime. Now if $2^{k-1} \equiv 1 \pmod{k^2}$ holds then the order of $2$ mod $p^2$ must divide $k-1$ for every prime $p \mid k$. Since $p$ does not divide $k-1$, it must be the case that all prime divisors of $k$ are Wieferich. Since none of the products of known Wieferich primes work, there is no "easy disproof" of the claim. Given the [current state of affairs](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL14/Klyve/klyve3.html), there are no composite numbers $k \leq 6.7\times10^{18}$ such that $2^{k-1} \equiv 1 \pmod{k^2}$. The reasoning above actually gives a characterization of the squarefree numbers $k$ that satisfy $2^{k-1} \equiv 1 \pmod{k^2}$. These are the squarefree base $2$ [pseudoprimes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_pseudoprime) whose prime factors are all Wieferich.

On the positive side, Carl Pomerance suggested to look at a paper of his with Zachary Franco, [On a conjecture of Crandall concerning the $qx+1$ problem](http://www.math.dartmouth.edu/~carlp/PDF/paper101.pdf). There, they consider Wieferich numbers which are characterized by $\operatorname{gcd}((2^{\ell(k)}-1)/k,k) \gt 1$, where $\ell(k)$ is the order of $2$ modulo $k$. This is much weaker than your condition $(\star)$ but Pomerance and Franco show that Wieferich nubers have asymptotic density $1$ in the odd numbers. While this is by no means affirmative, it does suggest that there might be composite solutions to the congruence $2^k \equiv 1 \pmod{k^2}$.

Comment: Before the birth of Math Overflow, this was asked in another forum, see ["Wieferich pseudoprimes"](http://forums.xkcd.com/viewtopic.php?f=17&t=23397).

Answer (score 0):

In an older essay I looked at the "composites"-generalization of Wieferich- and generalized Wieferich-primes. I found such solutions, and documented that cases in a couple of tables. Here is a screenshot of the table with "Wieferich-composites" (to base $2$:

> (...)
> [image]
> ...

*(from ["High fermat- and Euler-quotients"](http://go.helms-net.de/math/expdioph/fermatquotients.pdf) . Note: the essay is an amateur's work, not a true research paper)*